# What does a sheet of graphene look like?

Tags: material-science, graphene

1. What does a sheet of graphene look like?
2. At one atom thick, is it visible to the naked eye?
3. Can it be handled (by hand) with being torn?
4. Can it be felt at all?

[Assuming a large enough sheet exists.]

Comment: This is a partial answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Optical It can be seen because it absorbs about 2.5% of visible light between red and green.

Comment: A single atom thick sheet absorbs that much? Very surprising!

Comment: Yes I was a little surprised too.

Comment: It sounds like that graphene, when seen under a small angle, should block light quite easily. The mechanical properties indicate that one should be able to "feel" a sufficiently large stretched sheet of it, albeit even a slight touch will probably break a single sheet. So far the mechanical properties don't seem to have been useful for any of the "super"-materials that the media are promising to the public, though. It reminds me a little of the decade long battle of material science with taming ceramics, which, of course, was eventually successful.

Comment: This came from a throwaway comment in an article that casually mentioned that a hammock make of graphene could hold the weight of a cat (4kg), yet weigh less than one of its whiskers. Not exactly highly specified engineering terms... I assume we are some way away from making cat hammocks.

Comment: @user56093 I can great potential in the graphene cat hammock market of the future. Invest now!